# JQuery Table Sorter - PHP related

Tags: php, jquery, tablesorter

Apologies from the off if this is an amateurish question.
I am trying to get the Jquery Tablesorter plugin to work with a table generated with PHP from a MySql database. At the moment I'm unable to get the sorting to work. I'm thinking its something to do with the sequence of the javascript and php operating and may need to implement a callback in the javascript or something. Anyway code I have is:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#table1").tablesorter({ sortlist: [0,0] }); 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Database1", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM PlayerStats1 WHERE G>2 LIMIT 0,20");

echo "<table id=\"table1\" class=\"tablesorter\" border=1px>
<caption align=top>Stats</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
<th width=90px>Forename</th>
<th width=90px>Surname</th>
<th width=50px>Team</th>
<th width=40px>G</th>
<th width=50px>RPG</th>
<th width=50px>APG</th>
<th width=50px>TOPG</th>
<th width=50px>BPG</th>
<th width=50px>SPG</th>
<th width=50px>PPG</th>
</tr>
</thead>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {       
  echo "<tbody>";
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['FORENAME'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['SURNAME'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['TEAM'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td align='center'>" . $row['G'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col1' align='center'>" . $row['RPG'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col2' align='center'>" . $row['APG'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col3' align='center'>" . $row['TOPG'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col4' align='center'>" . $row['BPG'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col5' align='center'>" . $row['SPG'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td class='col6' align='center'><b>" . $row['PPG'] . "</b></td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  echo "</tbody>";
  }
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

If it is a case of implementing a call back- any guidance/code would be much appreciated.

Comment: don't think this is related to the problem, but: `<th width=90px>` is invalid code. It should be either `<th width='90'>` (without the `px`) or `<th style='width:90px;'>` (using `style` with the units in `px`). The code you've got might work, but could also cause problems, and definitely isn't standards-compliant so might throw browsers into quirks mode.

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with the sequence; your browser executes the Javascript, and as far as it's concerned, the PHP-generated HTML is the same as any HTML, so the fact that it's generated is irrelevant. I suggest you turn on debug mode in tablesorter and use Firebug and see if that illuminates the issue, otherwise I'm not seeing, on the surface, what could be causing a problem. Not that it might not be there, I'm just missing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

the Tbody tag should be called only once and outside of your TR loop.
TBody is a singular collection of ALL your table body TR elements. that's going to jack tablesorter up.

Comment: Good point, I didn't catch that the tbody was inside the loop. Yeah, put it outside, that's probably confusing tablesorter. Using multiple tbodies can be useful, but probably not in this case.